# How to print in VB?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, http, printing

I have a web application build using classic ASP and VB. How do I print a document from within the back end VB code?

```
Protected Sub btnPrint_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnPrint.Click

End Sub
```

What i am trying to do is get user to click on button a letter is generated and sent to printer?

Comment: this isn't classic asp OR vb. It's ASP.NET and VB.NET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [`window.print`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.print) javascript function which will open the print dialogon the client browser allowing him to choose the printer and print the page:

```
Protected Sub btnPrint_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnPrint.Click
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript([GetType](), "print", "window.print();", true)
End Sub
```

As a side note, what you have is not a classic ASP application with VB, you have a classic ASP.NET WebForms application using VB.NET as a code behind.

---

UPDATE:

As requested in the comments section here's how you could write a generic handler which will dynamically generate the HTML you would like to print:

```
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Services

Public Class Print
    Implements System.Web.IHttpHandler

    Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/html"
        context.Response.Write("<html><body onload=""window.print();""><table><tr><td>value1</td><td>value1</td></tr></table></body></html>")
    End Sub

    ReadOnly Property IsReusable() As Boolean Implements IHttpHandler.IsReusable
        Get
            Return False
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

Now simply navigate to `/Print.ashx`.

Comment: also within the code i want to build a letter for example and then print it

Comment: sorry it looks like GetType is some registered keyword in VB.NET. Try wrapping it in `[]`: `[GetType]()`.

Comment: sort of works but i dont want to print the current page. I want to send a load of text created in the vb to print

Comment: In this case you could redirect to some generic handler which will generate the necessary HTML you would like to print and include the `window.print()` javascript command inside the onload of the body.

Comment: @Beginner, sure, see my update. By the way this could simply be another `.aspx` page where you simply put the `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript` I have shown you in the `Page_Load` if you don't want to create one from scratch in the form of a generic handler (`.ashx`). In both cases when the user clicks the print button you could redirect to that page using `Response.Redirect`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3764/discussion-between-beginner-and-darin-dimitrov)

Answer (score 0):

you could look into some reports frameworks like CrystalReports (used to come with VS but you have to download it from SAP nowadays.

Here is a nice tutorial for the report-engine that comes packed into Visual Studio (I have to admit I don't have much experience with this but it looks fine to me): [Creating an ASP.NET Report](http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2010/05/09/creating-an-asp-net-report-using-visual-studio-2010-part-1.aspx)